# Get data from URL in a browser

Tags: java, android, oauth

The title might be a little misleading, so I'll try to explain it the best way I can. In my Android application I'm using OAuth authentication. At one point, I need to open up a browser window so the user can approve the application. Once they approve it, they get forwarded to another URL with some address parameters. What I need is to grab the value from one of the parameters and feed it back into my application.

What I'm kind of looking for is described in steps three and four in [this Android & OAuth tutorial](http://donpark.org/blog/2009/01/24/android-client-side-oauth), I'm just not exactly sure if I should go the way described in the article.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get URL parameters via JavaScript in the browser, try something like this:

```
function getURLParameters() {
  var keyValuePairs = location.search.split(/[&?]/g);
  var params = {};
  for (var i = 0, n = keyValuePairs.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var keyValuePair = keyValuePairs[i];
    var eqIndex = keyValuePair.indexOf("=");
    if (eqIndex >= 0) {
      params[decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair.substring(0, eqIndex))]
        = decodeURIComponent(keyValuePair.substring(eqIndex + 1));
    }
  }
  return params;
}
```

If the same URL parameter (by name) is specified twice, then it will only show up once in the output, but you could change this to return a multimap like object.

Comment: How would I be able to pass that to the Android application though?

Comment: @Chiggins, I understand now.  Your app is not just a thin wrapper around the app.  You *only* use it for auth.  Are you using `Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` to launch the browser?

Comment: @Chiggins, If you use `WebView` you should be able to get it via http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()

Comment: @Mike, I haven't looked into using a WebView, I've never used one before. Think I'd be able to save the URL then close out of the WebView?

Comment: @Mike, also, how would I know to grab the URL and close the WebView? I can't think of a way to trigger that.

Comment: @Chiggins, you can register a `WebClient` and override its `onPageFinished` event handler to receive notification that the page has finished loading and then get the URL at that time.  That won't get you a notification *only* when the page you want has loaded, you will still get a spurious notification when the authentication form loads and possibly on redirects, but it gives you a place to stand.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29